VPN Packet Tunneling in Swift
I have an Xray server using Vmess protocol. I want to implement a Packet Tunnel in Swift but can't find any resource or guide.
If anyone has any resource or guide links or can help me implement this ill be grateful. Also I'm willing to pay for this.
I've tried using GO package (Github link: https://github.com/v2ray/v2ray-core) to make an xcframework, but some methods are missing.
xcframework file function i used in Swift
open class CoreInstance : NSObject, goSeqRefInterface, CoreServerProtocol {
open var _ref: Any { get }


public init(ref: Any)

public init()

// skipped method Instance.AddFeature with unsupported parameter or return types

/**
 * Close shutdown the V2Ray instance.
 */
open func close() throws

// skipped method Instance.GetFeature with unsupported parameter or return types

// skipped method Instance.RequireFeatures with unsupported parameter or return types

/**
 * Start starts the V2Ray instance, including all registered features. When Start returns error, the state of the instance is unknown.
A V2Ray instance can be started only once. Upon closing, the instance is not guaranteed to start again.

v2ray:api:stable
 */
open func start() throws

}
this is the error i get in console while running the app
-[Swift.__SharedStringStorage incNum]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2813baa60
This is the core instance: <CoreServer: 0x280d92c10>
2024-10-25 17:17:37.515121+0500 V2Ray VPN[9474:580376] -[Swift.__SharedStringStorage incNum]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2801e8b40
2024-10-25 17:17:37.516905+0500 V2Ray VPN[9474:580376] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift.__SharedStringStorage incNum]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2801e8b40'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18179fc60 0x198fcfee4 0x1818706e8 0x18173954c 0x18173875c 0x10139e114 0x10139c3f8 0x100f805b4 0x100f7fc28 0x194faa3e8 0x1dbfd6b88 0x102044700 0x102045fc8 0x1020548ac 0x1020544fc 0x18175b014 0x1817184f8 0x18172b174 0x1a226e988 0x183f2da88 0x183cc6f78 0x100f82e9c 0x101e684d0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
missing Method probably due to skipped methods in xcframework.

Please show your callsite where you invoke this API.
